# Monotouch UITextfield character validation for ascii codes

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have some piece of WP8 code which does validation of text field when user starts entering

These event I receive them as KeyEventArgs in WP8
e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.D0 .... System.Windows.Input.Key.D9
also System.Windows.Input.Key.A ... system.Windows.Input.Key.Z

I had checked ShouldChangeCharacters that get the replacementString...

Now I should check by getting the ASCII codes for digits 0 to 9 and A to Z from the replacementString.. // How can I do this in a BETTER WAY ?

Comment: currently doing it this way `code` var newLength = textField.Text.Length + replacementString.Length - range.Length;    
    int asciivalue = replacementString.ToCharArray()[0];
    if (!(asciivalue >= 65  && asciivalue <= 90))  return false; `code`

Comment: What is replacementString supposed to mean?